# Parzen Window convergence of the mean

Tags: convergence, density-estimation

I'm studying the convergence of the mean in Parzen Window estimates, and am having trouble figuring out the intuition behind one particular step in the derivation. It goes from

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E\bigg[\frac{1}{V_n}\;\varphi\bigg(\frac{\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_i}{h_n}\bigg)\bigg]$$ to $$\int\frac{1}{V_n}\varphi\bigg(\frac{\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{v}}{h_n}\bigg)\;p(\mathbf{v})\;d\mathbf{v}$$

What I'm confused about is the relationship between $\mathbf{x}_i$ and $\mathbf{v}$, and why it is possible to directly substitute $\mathbf{x}_i$ with $\mathbf{v}$.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming $\mathbf x_i$ are iid:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E_{f(\mathbf{x_1},\dots, \mathbf{x_n})}\bigg[\frac{1}{V_n}\;\varphi\bigg(\frac{\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_i}{h_n}\bigg)\bigg] \\ = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E_{f(\mathbf{x_i})}\bigg[\frac{1}{V_n}\;\varphi\bigg(\frac{\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_i}{h_n}\bigg)\bigg]$$

Again, assuming $\mathbf x_i$ are iid and letting $\bf v$ follow the distribution of $\mathbf x_i$, call this distribution $p(\cdot)$:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nE_{f(\mathbf x_i)}\bigg[\frac{1}{V_n}\;\varphi\bigg(\frac{\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_i}{h_n}\bigg)\bigg] \\ = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\int\frac{1}{V_n}\varphi\bigg(\frac{\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{v}}{h_n}\bigg)\;p(\mathbf{v})\;d\mathbf{v}$$

We see that the summand does not depend on i.
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\int\frac{1}{V_n}\varphi\bigg(\frac{\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{v}}{h_n}\bigg)\;p(\mathbf{v})\;d\mathbf{v} \\ = \int\frac{1}{V_n}\varphi\bigg(\frac{\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{v}}{h_n}\bigg)\;p(\mathbf{v})\;d\mathbf{v}$$